# Join the table with one of the same field (codeigniter)

Tags: codeigniter, activerecord, join

Given the following table definitions:

**Table 1**: `pbk`

```
ID, GroupID, name, nohp
```

**Table 2**: `pbk_groups`

```
ID, name
```

I want to select all of the fields in the `pbk` table, and the field `name` in `pbk_groups` table. However, the field `name` in `pbk` table and `pbk_groups` have the similarities.

How to I write a script to join the table in controller, model and view using codeigniter?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT pbk.*, pbk_groups.name as name
FROM pbk
LEFT JOIN pbk_groups
ON pbk_groups.id=pbk.pbk_group_id
```

you can overwrite the name values like `pbk_groups.name as name` or you can set that to another variable so you can get both names `pbk_groups.name as groupname.

```
$this->db->select ( 'pbk.*,pbk_groups.name as name' );
$this->db->from ( 'pbk' );
$this->db->join ( "pbk_groups", "pbk_groups.id=pbk.pbk_group_id", "LEFT" );
$query = $this->db->get ();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$this->db->select('*');
$this->db->from('pbk');

$this->db->join('pbk_groups', 'pbk_groups.name= pbk.name');

$query = $this->db->get();
```

You can write this query in model or controller. If you are writing this query in model then return query result by

```
return $query->result_array();
```